# Number only input text field not working in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

Number only input not working in angularjs for pincode/zipcode. I have used ng-pattern as the following in jsp page and the controller:

Jsp page:

```
Pin:<input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" ng-pattern="numOnlyRegex" name="pin" required placeholder="Pin"/><br/>
```

Module:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp',[]);
```

Controller:

```
app.controller("numOnlyRegex",function($scope)
{
   $scope.numOnlyRegex = /^\d+$/; 
});
```

And the scr folder for js is:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/myAppRegistrationModule.js"></script>
<script src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/numOnlyRegex.js"></script>
```

Comment: Is your module deceleration is available in numOnlyRegex.js, If so, you have to do it like this  angular.module('myApp').controller('your js name',function(){}); not in the way you have specified above

Comment: @Hurix ok let me try

Comment: Tried the way you said: `angular.module('myApp',[]).controller("numOnlyRegex",function($scope)
{
   $scope.numOnlyRegex = /^\d+$/; 
});`

Comment: when I moved the js file to the location where jsp is present, its not taking any values on submit. I mean I cannot see any submitted values from text box in the url browser. Is this a problem?

Comment: Please check whether the js files are loaded  into your browser. Can you create a plunkr link for the same, Can debug further . Sample plnkr link for validation http://plnkr.co/edit/CbNzrl?p=preview

Comment: @Hurix How do I check if they are loaded in to browser?

Comment: @Hurix I tried a `alert("hi") from another js file from same location and its working